# Detect browser window in javascript

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I'm a newbie in javascript and I've to do the following operation: I have an asp .net application which load in a new window browser another content.

Through javascript, I need to refresh the popup which i opened before, but I don't know how I can find that new window.

I tried a simple `window.location.reload(true);` but this will cause a refresh only of the main browser window which launched the popup. Instead my intent is to refresh only the popup window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the window, give it a name (or store the return value of the window). Then, instead of `window.location.reload`, call `name.location.reload` where `name` is the name you gave the window.

Comment: Thank's, but my problem is that i haven't access to the window.open method (so i don't know the name). Is it possible to retrieve the name in other ways??

Answer (score 1):

If you open the window with `window.open()`, grab its return value.  That's a reference to the window object of the popup.  From there you can call `location.reload()`.  For example, this will open a window and then reload it again:

```
var popup = window.open('/somepage');
popup.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: Thank's, but my problem is that i haven't access to the window.open method (so i don't know the name). Is it possible to retrieve the name in other ways??

Comment: How exactly are you opening the popup then?

Comment: i'm using an external framework called visual webgui and i'm using an internal call which open the popup

Comment: I'm not familiar with that framework, but if it is at all decent it will have a way for you to grab a reference to the window and perform operations on it.  Have a search through the docs for the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Store a reference to your popup window and then instead of calling the `location.reload()` function on your main window, call it on the popup window, like this:

```
var myNewWindow = window.open(...);
myNewWindow.location.reload(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating the new window using Javascript?
if you are using `window.open()`, that function returns a reference to the new window, So you can do something like this:

```
var newWin = window.open();
newWin.location.reload(true);
```